# Algorithm to make all possible subsets of n items

Tags: algorithm, math, powerset, set-theory

I have n items and I need an algorithm to make all possible subsets of these.

What I really need is an algorithm that will make all possible partitions of these n items into two disjoint sets. But I thought all possible subsets would be a good place to start - then for each subset I can put all remaining items into other disjoint set.

Comment: Please, edit your question and add to it what you have already done to solve this issue.

Comment: So, combinations, as opposed to permutations? Meaning the set does not depend on order?

Comment: Now that you have established your need, try to draw up an algorithm that will satisfy your need.

Comment: Look at this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22280078/how-to-write-iterative-algorithm-for-generate-all-subsets-of-a-set.

Comment: Your are looking for [PowerSet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_set)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [our on-topic guidance](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) specifies that, "Questions asking for *homework help* must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it."

Comment: no, the order doesn't matter, just all different subsets.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2^n possible subsets on n items (including empty one).

So you can make loop for all integers in range `0..2^n-1` and map every integer `M` in this range onto corresponding subset: k-th item is part of subset `M` if k-th bit of `M` is set.

```
for M = 0 to 2^n-1 do
   x = M
   k = 0 
   while x <> 0 do
       if (x and 1) then //check if kth bit is set in x
           ......
       x = x >> 1  //shift right
       k = k + 1
```

Alternatively, you can make binary counter for the same range - for example, for the set `[0 0 1 1]` next set will be `[0 1 0 0]`

Comment: This makes a lot of sense, but how do I actually express M as a n-digit binary number so that I can create the Mth subset?